# Linking Validation js file to html file ERROR - Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "diabetestool.js"> </script>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

</head>

<body>
<form id = "test2" name = "test2">

<table cellpadding="2" width="20%" bgcolor="red"
align="center" 
cellspacing="2"

<tr>
<td colspan =2>
<center>  <font size = 4>FORM TO FILL IN </font></center>
</td>
</tr>


<td> Title </td>
<td> <select Name="Title">
<option value= "-1 selected"> select...</option>
<option value= "Mr"> Mr </option>
<option value= "Mrs"> Mrs </option>
<option value= "Miss"> Miss </option>
<option value= "Ms"> Ms </option>
<option value= "Master"> Master</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><input type ="text" name= "firstName" id ="firstName" size ="30"> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td> Last Name</td>
<td> <input type ="text" name ="lastName" id = "lastName" size ="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Health Authority Number</td>
<td> <input type ="text" name ="healthNumber" id = "healthNumber" size ="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Email</td>
<td> <input type ="text" name ="email" id = "email" size ="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Telephone Number</td>
<td> <input type ="text" name ="telephoneNumber" id = "telephoneNumber" size ="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan ="2"> <input type="submit" value="submit form" onsubmit="return validate()"; </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

this is my code to create the code for my contact form to be filled 
there are a selection of options

```
function validate ()
{
// Declare all the variables here
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var lastName =  document.getElementById("lastName").value;
var Title = document.getElementById("Title").value;
var healthNumber = parseInt(document,getElementById("healthNumber").value);
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

var validEmail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;


if(firstName!="" && lastName!= "" && Title!="" && email !="")
{
        if(email.match(validEmail))
        {
            alert("All Values Validated");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Enter a valid Email");
            return false;
        }
}
else
{
    alert("All Fields are required");
    return false;
 }



}
```

this is just a randomly created js validation code just to test to see if the validating process works with my code and then i will change it to actually do the proper validation i want
 the issue is that with my html page for my contact form after submitting, it just refreshes that page i have tried different things but not able to find a solution

Comment: What kind of an error are you getting?

Comment: the issue  i find is when using web console no errors are popping up, however what should be happening is when i submit my form , the validation should take place but it does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has lot of syntax error. I fix syntax error. Here is the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ngs96n0/13/

Use onsubmit in form tag something like that :

```
<form id = "test2" name = "test2"  onsubmit="return validate(event);">
```

and In JS:

```
function validate (e){
   e.preventDefault();
   .................
   .................
   .................
   .................
   .................
}
```

it will stop the form from refreshing.

Comment: i tried your changes but i still get the same issue

Comment: @MichaelWright. check the fiddle which i just have created. I added their link in my answer.

Comment: ok i went on it and when i run your edited version of the code i get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: great help it works perfectly on the fiddle  my only issue is getting it to work on my browser - i have this bit of code <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title> Contact Form </title>
<link href ="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src = "contactform.js"> </script>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

</head>
at the top of my html page could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

parseInt(document,getElementById("healthNumber").value);
Check the above line there is a , comma instead of. Dot . In document.getElementById("healthNumber").value;

Another one is close table element in html part, it will be solved
Thanks

Comment: Another one is close table element in html part - what do you mean by this?

Comment: i found the missing > in table and the . missing in healthnumber area but still the same issue im getting

Comment: The submit code must be in form tag,  not in the input tag.see the another answer which is mentioned with example. <form id = "test2" name = "test2"  onsubmit="return validate(event);"><table></table></form>

Comment: Also put return false; out of all conditions. Before last } closing braces.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your code 
such as calling the function in HTML

And "parseInt "function in JS

HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "diabetestool.js"> </script>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

</head>

<body>
<form id = "test2" name = "test2" onsubmit="validate()">

<table cellpadding="2" width="20%" bgcolor="red"
align="center" 
cellspacing="2"

<tr>
<td colspan =2>
<center>  <font size = 4>FORM TO FILL IN </font></center>
</td>
</tr>


<td> Title </td>
<td> <select Name="Title" id="Title">
<option value= "-1 selected"> select...</option>
<option value= "Mr"> Mr </option>
<option value= "Mrs"> Mrs </option>
<option value= "Miss"> Miss </option>
<option value= "Ms"> Ms </option>
<option value= "Master"> Master</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><input type ="text" name= "firstName" id ="firstName" size ="30"> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td> Last Name</td>
<td> <input type ="text" name ="lastName" id = "lastName" size ="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Health Authority Number</td>
<td> <input type ="text" name ="healthNumber" id = "healthNumber" size ="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Email</td>
<td> <input type ="text" name ="email" id = "email" size ="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Telephone Number</td>
<td> <input type ="text" name ="telephoneNumber" id = "telephoneNumber" size ="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan ="2"> <input type="submit" value="submit form" >
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

javascript:

```
// Declare all the iables here
var firstName;
 var lastName;
 var Title ;
 var healthNumber;
 var email ;

 validEmail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;

function validate ()
{
 firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
 lastName =  document.getElementById("lastName").value;
 Title = document.getElementById("Title").value;
// healthNumber = parseInt(document,getElementById("healthNumber").value);
 email = document.getElementById("email").value;

 validEmail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;


if(firstName!="" && lastName!= "" && Title!="" && email !="")
{
        if(email.match(validEmail))
        {
            alert("All Values Validated");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Enter a valid Email");
        }
}
else
{
    alert("All Fields are required");
 }



}
```